# How to fix statsmodel.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX in Python

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a model in sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX using the code presented below. Where do I need to fix it?

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

# ряд концов историй 2016.04.30 23:00 до 2016.05.31 17:00
start_range = '2016-04-30 23:00:00'
end_range = '2016-05-31 17:00:00'
time_range = pd.date_range(start_range, end_range, freq='H')
len(time_range)

forecast_juny = []
R = len(selected_cells)
for cell in tqdm_notebook(selected_cells):
    for time in time_range:
        n_kluster = labels[selected_cells.index(cell)] # номер кластера
        zone = typical_zones[n_kluster] # типичная для кластера ячейка
        param = best_param[zone]

        model_fitted = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog=stand_data_full[cell]
                                                                 [time - relativedelta(hours=60):time + relativedelta(hours=7)], 
                                                exog=stand_data_full[feature_list]
                                                                 [time - relativedelta(hours=60):time + relativedelta(hours=7)], 
                                                order=(param[0], d, param[1]), 
                                                seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], S)).filter(best_stand_model[zone].params)

        predicted_data = model_fitted.predict(time + relativedelta(hours=1), time + relativedelta(hours=6), dynamic=True)
        # обратное преобразование из стандартного
        predicted_data = predicted_data * data_std[cell] + data_mean[cell]
        forecast_juny.append((time, predicted_data))

print('len(forecast_juny):', len(forecast_juny))
```

I'm expecting output fitted model and print "len(forecast_juny): 72930".

But I received the error log presented below. I am really frustrated why this code did not work

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   4240             try:
-> 4241                 return self._searchsorted_monotonic(label, side)
   4242             except ValueError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _searchsorted_monotonic(self, label, side)
   4199 
-> 4200         raise ValueError('index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing')
ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    808             key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
--> 810         return self._get_with(key)
    812     def _get_with(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_with(self, key)
    813         # other: fancy integer or otherwise
    814         if isinstance(key, slice):
--> 815             indexer = self.index._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind='getitem')
    816             return self._get_values(indexer)
    817         elif isinstance(key, ABCDataFrame):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _convert_slice_indexer(self, key, kind)
   1749         else:
   1750             try:
-> 1751                 indexer = self.slice_indexer(start, stop, step, kind=kind)
   1752             except Exception:
   1753                 if is_index_slice:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
   1704 
   1705         try:
-> 1706             return Index.slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind=kind)
   1707         except KeyError:
   1708             # For historical reasons DatetimeIndex by default supports

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
   4105         """
   4106         start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step,
-> 4107                                                  kind=kind)
   4109         # return a slice

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_locs(self, start, end, step, kind)
   4312         end_slice = None
   4313         if end is not None:
-> 4314             end_slice = self.get_slice_bound(end, 'right', kind)
   4315         if end_slice is None:
   4316             end_slice = len(self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   4242             except ValueError:
   4243                 # raise the original KeyError
-> 4244                 raise err
   4246         if isinstance(slc, np.ndarray):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   4236         # we need to look up the label
   4237         try:
-> 4238             slc = self._get_loc_only_exact_matches(label)
   4239         except KeyError as err:
   4240             try:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _get_loc_only_exact_matches(self, key)
   4205         get_slice_bound.
   4206         """
-> 4207         return self.get_loc(key)
   4209     def get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1602             # needed to localize naive datetimes
   1603             key = Timestamp(key, tz=self.tz)
-> 1604             return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1606         if isinstance(key, time):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: Timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the date you specified could not be matched with the index. Usually, this happens because you're providing an index with dates that can't be matched to a frequency (e.g. monthly), in which case there would have been a warning message alerting you to this.

Comment: Could you please provide some advice how to fix it in my code?